# Compare every item of a list to every other item in a list checking if they belong to defined intervals

Tags: python, list

I have two lists a & b, with equal length N and values between [0, 1]. I want to check each pair of the two lists with same index (a[0] with b[0], a[1] with b[1] and so on) and based on their values, measure how many times the belong as pair to one of the following states.

Each element of the list can be in one of the following state:

1) [0]

2) (0, 0.1]

3) (0.1, 0.2]

.....

11)(0.9, 1)

12) [1]

My issue is that each element of a or b can be in one of those 12 states so their pairs have the possibility of being in one of the 12 * 12 = 144 final states.

Pair State    <-     State a  &  State b

Final State 1 <-State 1 & State 1

Final State 2 <-State 1 & State 2

Final State 3 <-State 1 & State 3

....

Final State 144 <- State 12 & State 12

If I only had one list the problem could be solved with a simple for loop and if/else statements. I zipped the two lists, but then the combinations are too many to proceed.

Any ideas?

As an example if I have:

a = [0, 0.1, 0.25,  0.1]

b = [1, 0.1, 0.4,  0.05]

There 144 defined possible pair of states so from the above 4 we have

State 1 & State 12 = 1 (from a[0]-b[0])

State 2 & State 2 = 2  (from a[1]-b[1] and a[3]-b[3])

State 4 & State 5 = 1  (from a[2]-b[2])

Comment: Yes, sure it can !

Comment: Can you provide an example for the initial two lists and the desired output?

Comment: what's your expected otuput? this is not clear at all ....

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your needs here! Give us a verifiable sample input and an output. Also tell us what you've written till now.

Comment: I provided a small input, 4 pair element comparisons found to to belong to 3 out of 144 possible states.

Comment: About this recent edit, I take it `State 1 & State 2` and `State 2 & State 1` are not the same thing.

Comment: No they are not and that is what makes the comparisons complex. The possible different pairs of states are in total 144.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get this right, given your two lists, you need to find out how many "pairs" contain items from the same interval.

Here's a little trick you could use:
Multiply by ten, then use `int()`to get rid of the decimal part.

```
a = [.11, .22, .33, .55]
b = [.16, .28, .38, .60]
pairs = 0

for (x, y) in zip(a, b):
    if int(x*10) == int(y*10):
        pairs += 1
print(pairs)
```

If zero is a state in itself, then you will need to adapt what I've posted above to account for that, since `int(0*10)` and `int(0,09*10)`gives the exact same result.

Following edits to the question : if you do have a "matrix" of states, then there might actually be a simple way out of this.

```
w = 12
states = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(w)] # Beware of [[0]*12]*12, that doesn't work

for (x, y) in zip(a, b):
    sx = int(x*10)
    sy = int(y*10)

    if (x != 0):
        sx +=1
    if (y != 0):
        sy += 1
    states[sx][sy] += 1
```

This creates a 12*12 table, and for each pair, increments the "cell" it belongs to. From there, you need to extract the number of pairs and prefix them with the appropriate "state x + state y" labels.

Last notes : if you are to output the result to a console, you might want to use the `pprint` module.

Comment: Nice trick, I didn't know about the ability to `sum` over a list of booleans. Also comes to my mind : Isn't my code above "wasting" time by creating a tuple ?

Comment: Only `zip` is creating a `tuple` - the `(x, y)` is just unpacking (aka adding another name binding) the items.

Comment: Makes sense, now that you say it :°

Comment: @ Prest thank you, but not probably I have not explained it correctly. I need to count the number of times each pair belongs to one of the 144 states. So in the end, I must take as an output 144 values.

Comment: Edited my answer in the meantime, using the same technique over a 12*12 table

Comment: The above doesn't quite work yet, but you get the idea.

Comment: This is what i need, thank you! I have not thought of creating the states in a matrix table which indeed helps a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! I've edited the answer, I think the "workaround" using `sx` and `sy`allows to store the results where they need to be now.

Comment: Yes, now they are stored exactly where i need, state {0} and state {1} for each element are included also!

Answer (score 0):

For the numpy version a similar machinery without an explicit loop.

```
import numpy as np

a = [.11, .22, .33, .55]
b = [.16, .28, .38, .60]
Ind = (10*np.array([a,b])).astype(int)
State_mat = np.zeros((12,12),dtype=int)
State_mat[Ind[0],Ind[1]] = 1
State_mat.tolist()
```

gives the same output